# EF6 Include only Base (not derived types) TPH

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
public class Transaction {
    //10 fields
    public Claim ClaimNavigate { get; set; }
}

public class Claim {
    //20 fields
}

public class Cms : Claim {
    //50 fields
}

public class Ub : Claim {
    //80 fields
}

dbContext.Transactions.Include(x => x.Claim).First()

dbContext.Claims.First()  // also returns all derived types, how to return Base only?
```

Is there a way to Include only fields of Claim, and not auto adding to sql all fields of all inherited claims?

Comment: You can't filter with Include method. But you can filter the content of ClaimNavigate based on the type you want. The problem is you may have a Select N + 1 query.

Comment: I hoped there should be some hack, option, override ...

Comment: dbContext.Claims.Cast<Claims>().First(); should do the trick. Or dbContext.Claims.OfType<Claims>().First();

Comment: No it doesn't do a trick. OfType do a trick when you trigger Cms to eliminate loading of unneeded Ub.